# Import gmail (emails and folders) to Outlook web

Tags: outlook.com, outlook-on-the-web

Apparently, it was possible to import data from Gmail to Outlook Web (not Outlook client), as this post suggests. The option was here:

[image]

Unfortunately, that option is no longer there for Outlook web:

[image]

How can I import my emails from Gmail into Outlook Web? I also found this website but it doesn't give me enough confidence.